# How to get two clients of a server to transfer files

Tags: wcf, communication, file-transfer, channel

In WCF, how exactly would I need to go about getting two clients in a server, such as two people connected to a chat room of sorts, to be able to transfer files to one another without that data going through to the server itself?

Is there a way to do it by the server passing the callback channel of each to each other so they can call each others respective callback methods which might contain a file transfer method?

I'm a little bit fuzzy on this. Again, I do not want the data to have to transfer through to the server if I can avoid it, but rather directly between the two clients.

EDIT:

I have figured out logically how I intend to accomplish this. I have the two clients connected to the chat server. The client who wants to send a file creates an entirely separate ServiceHost using a different contract, and executes a method on the server asking to send a file to a particular user. The server then responds by asking the target client if they would like to accept. The information passed along is the address, binding and contract, or at the very least the address and everything else is just assumed since it's all held in the same assembly.

When the client accepts, he connects to the new service using the information given to it from the chat server. This creates an entirely new connection between the two clients and removes the chat server from the equation.

The problem I'm having now, is that I cannot get the IP address automatically of the client who is initially making the file transfer request, and thus I cannot pass it down along the line to the other client to connect to his service. I have tried the methods described to get IP address using the OperationContext message properties and extracting the IP, but it doesn't provide the WAN IP Address I need.

How do other chat services accomplish this? Do they make requests through sites such as whatismyip address or their own ones to pull the IP address of a client first?

If I can't figure out the IP Address, then I will have to have the user manually enter his own IP address, which seems really clunky.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Assuming reasonable firewalls and protections, how would client A have access to client B?

Comment: Well that's what I'm trying to figure out. How to get it to work. Many chat applications have the ability to transfer files directly to the user you're chatting with, without the information passing through the server first.

I'm trying to figure out how to do that with WCF.